# Кнопка Esс не выполняет свою функцию

Tags: ubuntu

Установил ubuntu 16.04. При нажатии на escape он приглушает микрофон. Так было из коробки. Ничего не менял. Как его перевести в норм режим?

Comment: Вы хотите перенастроить горячие клавиши?

Comment: ну по сути escape по умолчанию должен делать какие то манипуляции

Comment: Нажимаю... ничего не происходит. Что Вы хотите от этого действия?

Comment: Предлагаю отправить вопрос на доработку, так как непонятно, что автор хочет от кнопки `ESC`

Comment: @hedgehogues Что по сути делает кнопка esc в любой норм ОС? Отменяет какое то действие - вот тоже самое я хочу чтобы оно делало и в моей системе. Такое явление я вижу впервые. Ставил убунту, потом снес - поставил kde. Одно и тоже действие выполняет эта кнопка- вкл -выкл микрофон.

Comment: Клавиатура точно рабочая? Есть возможность проверить с другой клавиатурой?